# Multiplication array with coefficient TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, arrays, loops, scalar, vector-multiplication

I try to make a multiplication of an array D_0 with some coefficients for obtaining another array f_0 but I get:
only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars, why?
Why can I have the paramerter Re as a vector althought I did not initialize it. I tried with f_0 as well without loop but I get the same error.

Code:
import math
import numpy as np

```
V_dot = np.array([[3, 1, 2, 1]])
rho_air = 1.2
L  = np.array([[10 ,8, 10, 8]])
mu = 1.8*10**-5
delta_P = 1
v_air = np.array([[5 ,3, 5, 3]])
epsilon = 0.2/1000 
m_dot = V_dot * rho_air
D_0 = (4*m_dot/(math.pi*rho_air*v_air))**(1/2)
D_1 = D_0
Re  = (v_air * D_0 * rho_air) / mu
print("Re", Re)
f_0= 0*D_0
for i in range(0, len(D_0)): 
    f_0 = (-2*math.log((epsilon/D_0[i])/3.7065))**-2
print('f_0', f_0,)
```

Re [[291346.24815789 130294.00317411 237883.21548704 130294.00317411]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that math.log can only deal with scalars, what you want to use is the log function of the numpy library, which can be applied element wise to the array. Change math.log by np.log as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import math

V_dot = np.array([[3, 1, 2, 1]])
rho_air = 1.2
L  = np.array([[10 ,8, 10, 8]])
mu = 1.8*10**-5
delta_P = 1
v_air = np.array([[5 ,3, 5, 3]])
epsilon = 0.2/1000 
m_dot = V_dot * rho_air
D_0 = (4*m_dot/(math.pi*rho_air*v_air))**(1/2)
D_1 = D_0
Re  = (v_air * D_0 * rho_air) / mu
print("Re", Re)
f_0= 0*D_0
for i in range(0, len(D_0)): 
    f_0 = (-2*np.log((epsilon/D_0[i])/3.7065))**-2
print('f_0', f_0,)
```

Comment: Glad to help @chrisis!

Comment: I have a nother problem by cojntinuing with the same program

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Below my problem

Comment: I've added another answer @chrisis please check it!

Answer (score 0):

For this new issue, you can solve it by doing two things. The first thing is to create an numpy array instead of a list. The second thing, you should change all(e) to e.all(), please refer to the following [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html). You can find these corrections in the following code:

```
import numpy as np

V_dot = np.array([[3, 1, 2, 1]])
rho_air = 1.2
L  = np.array([[10 ,8, 10, 8]])
mu = 1.8*10**-5
delta_P = 1
v_air = np.array([[5 ,3, 5, 3]])
epsilon = 0.2/1000 
m_dot = V_dot * rho_air
D_0 = (4*m_dot/(math.pi*rho_air*v_air))**(1/2)
D_1 = D_0
Re  = (v_air * D_0 * rho_air) / mu
print("Re", Re)
f_0 = (-2*np.log((epsilon/D_0)/3.7065))**-2
print('f_0', f_0,)
delta_P_tot = delta_P*L
f_1 = f_0
f_2 = 0
e   = np.ones(len(D_0))
while e.all() > 0.0001:
    D_1 = ((f_1 * L)/delta_P_tot )* rho_air * (v_air)**2
    print('D_1', D_1, '[m]')
    Re  = (v_air * D_1 * rho_air) / mu
    print('Re', Re, )
    f_2=(-2*np.log((epsilon/D_1)/3.7065 + 
    2.5226/(Re*np.sqrt(f_1))))**-2
    print('f_2', f_2,)
    e = abs(f_1-f_2)
    print('e', e, )
    f_1 = f_2
```